# Calling Class Method in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple class with one method.  How can I create 2 additional columns in a pandas dataframe where 1 column is a column of class objects and column 2 calls the class method.  I've tried the below but it returns "Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1"

```
class test1:

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def mult(self):
    
    return self.x*self.y


data = {'x': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'y': [5, 6, 1, 2]}
fpd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fpd['class'] = test1(fpd['x'], fpd['y'])
fpd['method'] = fpd.apply(lambda x: x['class'].mult(), axis=1)
```

what I'd like it to return:

```
    x   y   class                                         method
0   3   5   <__main__.test1 object at 0x000001E84ED6C388> 15
1   2   6   <__main__.test1 object at 0x000001E84ED6C388> 12
2   1   1   <__main__.test1 object at 0x000001E84ED6C388> 1
3   0   2   <__main__.test1 object at 0x000001E84ED6C388> 0
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fpd['class'] = test1(fpd['x'], fpd['y'])
fpd['method'] = fpd['class'].apply(lambda x: x.mult()).iloc[0]
fpd
```

**Output**

```
    x   y       class                                 method
0   3   5   <__main__.test1 object at 0x1205bd3a0>  15
1   2   6   <__main__.test1 object at 0x1205bd3a0>  12
2   1   1   <__main__.test1 object at 0x1205bd3a0>  1
3   0   2   <__main__.test1 object at 0x1205bd3a0>  0
```

**Explanation**
One way is to apply `mult` function on  `class` column, `transform` can also be used instead of `apply`.